# How can I load a string based on resource identifier?

Tags: c++, winapi, resources

I'm reading an entry from the registry that comes out something like:

`@%SystemRoot%\\System32\\wscsvc.dll,-200`

I need to actually load the string from the file.

I found [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776416.aspx) which describes how the number on the end behaves (negative == specific resource ID, positive == the nth resource in the file), but I'm confused as to how one might load the resource. The `ExtractIcon` function seems to do the resource loading I need, but it returns an `HICON`, not a string.

How might I load the string from the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load the DLL with [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx), load the string with [`LoadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647486%28VS.85%29.aspx), and then unload the DLL (assuming you don't need anything else from it) with [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683152%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wscsvc.dll");
if(hDll != NULL)
{
    wchar_t *str;
    if(LoadStringW(hDll, +200, (LPWSTR)&str, 0) > 0)
        ;  // success!  str now contains a (read-only) pointer to the desired string
    else
        ;  // handle error
    FreeLibrary(hDll);
}
else
    ;  // handle error
```

Note that `LoadLibrary` (and pretty much any other function that takes in a filename) does not understand environment variables like `%SystemRoot%`.  You'll have to use a function such as [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265%28VS.85%29.aspx) to expand the environment variables in the DLL filename before passing it to `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Woah.. do I feel dumb. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of string is called an "indirect string". The easiest way to get one is to call the [SHLoadIndirectString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shloadindirectstring) function that's meant exactly for that.

> Extracts a specified text resource when given that resource in the
>   form of an indirect string (a string that begins with the '@' symbol).